# App-prefs for iOS 11 Settings -> Control Center

Tags: ios, swift, settings

Do you know if it's possible to open Settings -> Control Center from within a swift app?  iOS 11...

I know the following will open Settings:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"App-Prefs:root")!)
```

Comment: Irrelevant to the answer you're seeking, but use `URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)` to open Settings

Comment: Thanks.  Changed for Swift 4.x `URL(string:UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)`